# Neo4j 3 index performance with high cardinality

Tags: neo4j

This question is about how the cardinality of a vertex property affects the performance of an index created on this property.

In Neo4j 3, from my understanding, user supplied vertex IDs cannot be given. Instead, to create an "ID" that is user-supplied, we could create an 'id' property value and create an index on this. How is the performance of a retrieval using the id index - a value with high cardinality - affected by the size of the graph?

A follow up question that may also shed some light on this is: how is the index in Neo4j constructed?

Comment: Note: from the [Neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) they state:

"A database index is a redundant copy of information in the database for the purpose of making retrieving said data more efficient. This comes at the cost of additional storage space and slower writes, so deciding what to index and what not to index is an important and often non-trivial task."

My guess is they just store as a hash map of property value to vertex id(s), but it is never explicitly stated

Comment: Lucene has been used under the hood for the indexing component, though in the last couple minor versions work has been done to migrate to neo4j's own native indexing solutions, mostly for the sake of write performance. You can expect `log(n)` lookup times via the index.